# Due Date is not updating on google

Tags: google-tasks

I tried to update the due date with rest API call out but is not updating on google and there is no error and exception for that too.
I tried this from google developer console but it is not updating on google and there is no error too.

Comment: Hello Nazia, the question looks uncompleted: please, provide more information about the issue you are experiencing and a minimal code or steps to follow to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hello Yuri,
Thanks for the response.
I am trying to update the google Task dueDate via google developer console where I have to specify the Task-list Id and Task Id and the dueDate value but the dueDate is not updating on google task.
The Google Task will not reflect the updated date.
here is the screenshot for the developer console :https://prnt.sc/q609im.

Is the dueDate of the Google Task is only readable?

Comment: Did the below answer worked to you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you do not add the id on the Body you get a `400 response error`, it shouldn't be like this, but this should definitely work:

```js
{
  "due": "2019-12-25T00:00:00.000Z",
  "id": "ekFnZHl5eGt0MG5oaFZZQg"
}
```

[image]